# Question about the religious life of beni Israel in Egypt before the Exodus?

Tags: avodah-zarah, pharaoh, exodus

How was the religious life of beni Israel in Egypt before the Exodus?

It is well known that the ancient Egyptian viewed their kings as gods, because the divine power of kingship was incarnated in them, and they did worship many of those kings.

Did beni Israel engage in such acts of worshipping the Egyptian kings? Is there any mention in Judaism, that the Egyptians took their king as god?

What do the sources of Judaism tell us about the religious life of beni Israel in Egypt before the Exodus?

Comment: What transpired across the entire nation, meaning individual behavior was like with any nation. There was a wide range behavior from one individual to the next. In general, historical sources say the behavior of the children of Israel was ethical and law abiding. But over many years of persecution by other segments of Egyptian society, the behavior of some Jewish individuals declined. Prejudice and persecution takes a toll over time.

Comment: Rashi to Exodus 7:15 says that Pharaoh claimed to be a god so he had to "use the bathroom" in secret in order to keep up the facade.

Comment: @Derdeer ..any other older commentaries mention the same? thanx